# SHGetKnownFolderPath Какой правильный синтаксис?

Tags: c++, winapi

Пытаюсь найти файл с помощью SHGetKnownFolderPath

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>
#include <sstream>
#define EXE L"/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"

bool func()
{
    wchar_t *path = EXE;
    if (SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, 0, &path) != S_OK)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Но при попытке найти инициализировать `path` у меня ошибка

```
E0144   значение типа "const wchar_t *" нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа "wchar_t *" Project1    C:\Users\user\Source\Repos\Project1\Project1\Source.cpp 9
```

Хотелось бы знать какой будет правильный синтаксис для инициализации переменной?

Comment: ошибка E0144 не имеет никакого отношения к SHGetKnownFolderPath. зачем вы вообще пытаетесь присвоить указателю в начале какое-то значение?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7448057/9123401

Comment: @Harry Я видел это решение и уже пробовал его, проблема там в том что переменная так и не инициализируется  то есть она равна 0, из-за этого всегда возвращается true

Comment: @krime , SHGetKnownFolderPath не имеет ничего общего с поиском файлов. Она для получения путей специальных папок. И переменная path там используется только для возврата значения из функции, инициализировать её не имеет никакого смысла.

Comment: Ну конкретно в данной ситуации всё просто: указатель на константные данные присваивается указателю на просто данные - так нехорошо... `const wchar_t* path = EXE` будет работать :)